# Does the “Pipelines of Pipelines” feature work between two different projects

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I’m trying to trigger a pipeline job in Project B from another in Project A. Is this allowed?

Is it possible to use [Pipelines of Pipelines](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipeline+of+Pipelines) feature for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using the TriggerPipeline step, provided the project integration has permission to trigger that pipeline.

Reference: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/TriggerPipeline

This step takes projectKey as a configuration, so from project A you can trigger a step in project B